# Are there any cheap, wide tubular front wheels?

Tags: road-bike

I was recently involved in a crash, which has cracked my front clincher wheel. I'd like to give tubulars a go and would like a wide rim so that I can fit some 700c x 25-28 mm tyres without the tyre becoming bulbous and greatly increasing drag, while enjoying the added comfort of a wider tyre. Are there any options for less than £100? Most of the options seem to be full carbon constructions, which I cannot afford and do not brake well in the wet anyway.

Comment: Product recs are off topic here but I will say that Velocity Major Toms are a really good choice in this category.

Comment: Just to be clear, the width/shape of the rim isn't going to affect the shape of the tire with tubulars. Also, if you're trying to save money, tubulars are not a good choice in general.

Comment: HED Belgium tubular

Comment: "pick any one - Cheap or Tubular"    I suspect you're mixed tubular (tubs/sew ups/cotton tyres/pro racing tyres) with tubeless (like a car, no tubes)

Answer (score 1):

The main reason people tend to use tubular tyres is that they are generally lighter than clincher counterparts. If you do wish to use a more budget-friendly alloy wheel, then going tubular isn't going to gain you too much weight savings. This is the reason manufacturers don't produce tubular alloy wheels. But if you want to save weight on wheels, try tubeless.